# How to Add or Update value in C# Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I faced this type of code and it seems to me that it can be more cleaner. What do you think of that? Can I use some function to do it better?

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        foreach (var n in nums)
        {
            if (dictionary.ContainsKey(n))
                dictionary[n]++;
            else
                dictionary.Add(n, 1);
        }
```

I tried to use "TryGetValue" method but it didn't help

Comment: since .net framework 2 you can just write `dictionary[n]++` no need to look if key exists.

Comment: @SebastianSiemens - are you sure https://dotnetfiddle.net/onhI33

Comment: @RandRandom You are right. The run-time processing of a postfix increment or decrement operation of the form x++ or x-- will invoke get before invoking set. The get will throw exception if element is not present.